# How many digits are needed given a certain number of assignation?

Tags: combinatorics

The similar questions I have found ([Q1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1874523/how-many-3-digit-numbers-can-be-formed-using-the-digits-2-3-4-and-5-as-often-a), [Q2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3383533/total-number-of-4-digit-codes-with-repeated-digits) for example) take a more statistical approach while my approach is more a problem-solving approach or a purely numerical approach. The math question I'm struggling with is:

> How many digits does it take to assign numbers to 182 employees using the numbers from 1 to 182? For example, it takes 15 digits to assign numbers to 12 employees (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12).

I don't know if it's because I'm not native english speaker, but it doesn't make sense to me that "*it takes 15 digits to assign numbers to 12 employees*". As far as I know:

- Maths have 10 digits, from 0 to 9.
- The number 234 has 3 digits: 2,3, and 4.
- Using the numbers from 1 to 100, to assign 2 employees I would need two digits: `1`, `2`. Or only 1 digit: `1`, `11`.
- With 10 digits (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) I don't see any restriction to assignation.
- Using only two digits (like 1 and 2) from numbers 1 to 99, I could assign until 6 employees: `1`,`2`,`11`,`22`,`12`,`21`.
- In all cases above, the number of digits needed is less than the quantity of numbers to assign.

So, **how does it takes 15 digits to assign numbers to 12 employees using numbers from 1 to 182?**.

- Using a combination of all 10 digits (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) the 12 assignations could be `1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`,`6`,`7`,`8`,`9`,`10`,`11`,`12`.
- Using a minimal combination of digits (3: 1,2,3), the assignations could be: `1`,`11`,`111`,`112`,`113`,`121`,`122`,`123`,`131`,`132`,`133`,`2`.
- And even more, what are those 15 digits if maths only has 10 digits?

I have found similar questions ([It took 2040 digits to assign every employee a number. How many employees are there?](https://brainly.in/question/36762823)) with a detailed math answer but still doesn't make sense to me, as I have explained my reasons above and wondering if it's a problem-solving perspective or language perspective maybe?

Comment: "15 digits" here means that the total number of digits in *all* the numbers used is 15, counting repetitions.

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to count the number of digits if all the serial numbers are laid out in a line.

so $1-9 = 9$ digits
$10-99 = 2\times90$ digits
$100-182 = ?$
Add up